# Parsing html tags with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have been given an url and I want to extract the contents of the `<BODY>` tag from the url.
I'm using Python3. I came across `sgmllib` but it is not available for Python3.

Can someone please guide me with this? Can I use `HTMLParser` for this?

Here is what i tried:

```
import urllib.request
f=urllib.request.urlopen("URL")
s=f.read()

from html.parser import HTMLParser
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered   some data:", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(s)
```

this gives me error : TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: "please guide me":  Will do.  Search.  It's been asked.  Many, many times.  After you do the search (in the upper right corner), feel free to ask **specific** questions based on the answers already given.

Comment: to be specific can we parse url in parser.feed() method?

Comment: @ghbhatt: show us a example of what you need. Otherwise see my answer is this what you are asking.

Comment: @RanRag: I did edit my question. please have a look at it.

Comment: [Have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114722/python-html-parsing-that-actually-works) [you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717541/parsing-html-in-python) [done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783385/processing-html-files-python) [a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694637/processing-a-html-file-using-python) [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)?

Comment: @S.Lott: i have posted my specific problem

Comment: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/html.parser.html

Comment: Please fix your tags.  Not [python].   [python3.x]

Comment: if the character encoding of the html page is known then to [extract text from `<body>` tag using HTMLParser you could do](http://ideone.com/gtaju).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To fix the TypeError change line #3 to

s = str(f.read())

The web page you're getting is being returned in the form of bytes, and you need to change the bytes into a string to feed them to the parser.

Comment: You should find the encoding from the HTTP headers so you know what encoding to use.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at your `s` variable its type is byte.

```
>>> type(s)
<class 'bytes'>
```

and if you take a look at [Parser.feed](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html#HTMLParser.HTMLParser.feed) it requires a string or unicode as an argument.So,do

```
>>> x = s.decode('utf-8')
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> parser.feed(x)
```

or do `x = str(s)`.

Comment: It seems that we gave the same answer with in a minute of each other.

Comment: You should find the encoding from the HTTP headers so you know what encoding to use.